# Find the diameter of a set faster than $O(|M|^2)$

Tags: algorithms, metric-spaces

$M$ is a finite set of points in a metric space. I want to calculate the diameter of the set, i.e. the greatest distance between two points. Is there a smarter way to do this than to calculate the distance between all pairs of points?

$$ \delta = \max_{x,y\in M} d(x,y) $$

I suppose the triangle inequality could let me know that some distance don't have to be calculated, but it seems like a lot of work to do those checks, and the distance function isn't very expensive.

In case someone was wondering, the points are longitude-latitude points and the distance function the Great Circle distance (which is a metric).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be done in $O(n$log$n)$, where $n$ is the number of points. The algorithms that I saw use the Euclidean distance, but I believe that it can be replaced by any metric distance measure. I am not aware of the Great Circle distance, but if it is metric, then this method should work.

The idea is to compute the convex-hull of the points, which can be done in $O(n$log$n)$, and then find the pair of furthest points from the vertices of this convex hull in $O(n)$ time.

Have a look at a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321989/greatest-linear-dimension-2d-set-of-points) question on Euclidean distances. Some description of the algorithm can be found [here](http://www.tcs.fudan.edu.cn/rudolf/Courses/Algorithms/Alg_ss_07w/Webprojects/Qinbo_diameter/2d_alg.htm). Here is a [paper](http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/07/23/54/PDF/RR-4233.pdf) treating diameter calculations in $d$ dimensions.

Comment: But then you would have to embed the metric space in $R^{|M|}$ or some other Euclidean space, which you can do, but you need again all non-trivial distances.

Comment: @Thomas I am afraid I don't quite follow. Here, $M$ is the set of points and not the number of dimensions. Also, I was under the impression that since the Great Circle distance is metric, simply replacing each computation of $d(a, b)$  from the 2D Euclidean distance to the Great Circle distance will work. Is that an incorrect assumption?

Comment: Well, you would have to embed a general metric space in a vector space in order to construct the convex hull. I'm not sure if you can do it directly on the sphere.